# mingw-w64 cannot link to libsodium

Tags: c++, linux, mingw-w64, libsodium

I am building a c++ project, where I need to support multiple platforms. Because I mainly use Linux, I am trying to compile project for Windows also on Linux.

I am using a `mingw` compiler. It is similar to g++, but i have problems with linking `libsodum` library to my project.

I am acutally using cmake, but this is a simple patch of code, which still recreates a problem.

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sodium.h>

int main() {
    if (sodium_init() == -1) {
        std::cout << "Sodoum init failed" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

in same folder I have copied content of `libsodium-win64` folder, in which are pre-built binaries for `libsodium`. It now looks like this:

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── libsodium-18.dll
│   └── libsodium-8.def
├── compile
├── include
│   ├── sodium
│   │   ├── core.h
│   │   ├── ... (and lot of other .h files)
│   │   └── version.h
│   └── sodium.h
├── lib
│   ├── libsodium.a
│   ├── libsodium.dll.a
│   ├── libsodium.la
│   └── pkgconfig
│       └── libsodium.pc
└── test.cpp
```

I am now trying to compile this with `mingw`.

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ test.cpp \
-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc \
-Llib -lsodium -Iinclude
```

And this returns me an error:

```
/tmp/ccyODazj.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `sodium_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have also tried to compile my own `libsodium` binaries with mingw, but this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Pre-built how? It has to be with a compatible compiler version and possibly even compiler settings. For example, you cannot mix and match binaries built with Microsoft Visual C++ and GCC. The error message makes me suspect a problem along these lines.

Comment: @besc I used pre-built binaries for mingw. I also built them from their github source on my linux machine, so they weren't built with Visual C++.

Comment: Are you saying you built the sodium libraries yourself natively on Linux and then copied them to Windows and now are trying to link them on Windows?

Comment: No, I am doing everythin on Linux. I am just compiling with Mingw. I have successfully compiled hello, world and it worked on Windows, my problem is that I have no idea how to link static library files.